# Why does calling setState in ComponentDidMount cause error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm assuming that the package [react-virtual-list](https://github.com/developerdizzle/react-virtual-list) calls `setState` when using `VirtualList`, but that shouldn't cause an issue inside `componentDidMount` right?

`Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the vlist component.`

`componentDidMount = () => {
    this.MyVirtualList = VirtualList({container: this._itemsList})(this.MyList)
  }`

Comment: Can you post the code that makes up your component?

Comment: what is ```this.MyVirtualList```? is that a function? show more code please.

Answer (score 0):

You are "initializing" a component into a variable, but your are not mounting it.

To mount a component, the component should be in the render method, otherwise the component will not be mounted in the DOM.

Why are you doing that logic? Maybe, you should render the component and, then, make it visible or not. It's the easiest way.

Bye